# netbeans shows blank interface

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to open Netbeans IDE (version 12.3) but it shows me a blank screen.

Please if you have a solution for that.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on how to improve your question.

Comment: Reinstall netbeans.

Comment: Reboot your machine after verifying that you have the latest version of NetBeans installed.

Comment: I installed the latest version after I restarted my computer and it works.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a proper answer but here is how I resolved the same type of error that happened with me in NetBeans 12.4:

1. Uninstall NetBeans.
2. Uninstall JDK.
3. Check for the version of NetBeans and JDK compatibility (in your case i.e. NetBeans 12.3 you will need JDK 8,11 or 15)
4. Install the compatible JDK.
5. Install NetBeans.

This might now resolve the issue.

Also, there might be issues in uninstalling NetBeans saying an instance of NetBeans is already running, if so follow the steps down below:

1. Close NetBeans from task manager (might be running in background tasks).
2. Type run and click on it in start menu(or press windows key + R).
3. Type "%AppData% in run and hit enter.
   [AppData Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXLs0.png)

4. Search for NetBeans in the pop up and select the sub folder of your desired version (the one you wish to delete).
5. In there you will find a lock file, delete it
[The lock file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnkh3.png)

6. Now uninstall NetBeans using command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried NetBeans 12.3 with JDK 15 as suggested in the comments and and it worked.